# Names of device not being shown in bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

Bluetooth works like a charm on my machine. However, `bluetoothctl` doesn't show the device names in discovery. What's stranger is that when running `bluetoothctl info <whatever-the-mac-adress-is>`, I get the name of the device I'm using.

Is there some place where I can customize bluetoothctl, and make it show device names on discovery ?

To be more precise, I get this result :

```
[NEW] Device 04:69:F8:A8:72:A2 04-69-F8-A8-72-A2
[NEW] Device 5B:72:90:C2:09:16 5B-72-90-C2-09-16
```

And `info` shows name only for devices that I used months ago. I suppose the error has to do with the current kernel or the current bluez release.

I'm using Artix Linux (with Runit) on kernel 5.16.10 and bluetoothctl 5.63.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that I was in a situation where all devices didn't have names. So not a software-level issue, or a real issue at all.